# Checking style names in Word against a list of permitted styles

Tags: vba, ms-word, styles, names

I have 4,000 records in my knowledge base, almost all in Word format. Many are formatted to our pre-set styles, of which there are about 20. Now we are implementing new style names :( and I want to write a macro to look at batches of records, change 'Style A' to 'New Style A', 'Style B' to 'New Style B' etc etc. I can do this but would like to ask ***how to check whether a paragraph's current style name is one of our 20 pre-set styles***. For example, if a style name is a standard Word style, or a style pulled in from elsewhere, I want to do something other than convert it to a new style. Many thanks!

Comment: If you are only implementing new style _names_, then why don't you just _rename_ the styles in the document?

Answer (score 0):

To find the style name of a selected paragraph, use:

```
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Style.NameLocal  ' or Name
```

To work on a built-in style, use:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
```

with `wdStyleNormal` a built-in Word constant, of which there are many for all (most) of the standard styles. I bieleve you can use a style name to work on one of your own (not built-in) styles. Lookup `Styles` in help for details.

The following macro I used to distribute (copy) styles from a prepared template to the user's Normal template:

```
Sub CopyStyles()
Dim n, src, dst
    '
On Error Resume Next
    src = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
    dst = NormalTemplate.FullName
    '
    ' Copy styles
    '
    n = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore
    ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).NameLocal
    ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = n
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading3).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading4).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading5).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading6).NameLocal

    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleTOC1).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleTOC2).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleTOC3).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleTOC4).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleTOC5).NameLocal
    Application.OrganizerCopy Source:=src, Destination:=dst, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles, Name:=ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleTOC6).NameLocal

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul. My macro loads the dotx containing the new styles and the style changes work OK. But what I want to do is to interrogate every paragraph, and see if its style is one of mine or a built-in. Kind of like you would do a vlookup in Excel. I guess I could code 'if old_para_style = my_style_1 or old_para_style = my_style_2...  ...  ...my_style_20' but that's not very elegant and would probably take a long time to run. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You can do a `Select Case old_para_style\ Case my_style1....\Case Default:....\End Select`. This lets VB optimize the string matching.

Comment: Thanks @Paul - I'll give it a go

Comment: Thanks @Paul - much better!

Comment: Which answer is "much better"? If it has helped you then you can upvote or accept the answer, that's how this site works (click arrows on the left side to up- or down-vote and click number in the middle to accept)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood your question wrong. Here are a few examples that are maybe more in the direction of what you look for:

```
Sub test()
Dim para As Paragraph

    ' rename a style of the document
    '
    On Error GoTo lbl_NoSuchStyle
        ActiveDocument.Styles("TestStyle1").NameLocal = "TestStyle2"
    On Error GoTo 0
lbl_NoSuchStyle:
    '
    ' Check styles of all paragraphs
    '
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        Select Case para.Format.Style.NameLocal
            Case "Req"
                Debug.Print "Isa Req"
            Case "TestStyle2"
                para.Style = wdStyleHeading3  ' change style to another style
            Case Else
                Debug.Print "Unknown Style"
        End Select
    Next para

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul I up-arrowed one of your answers but not displayed publicly as I have too few posts..